# Filter with another table's attribute (one to many) in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Filter with another table's attribute (one to many) in Rails

I'm a beginner on rails and currently working on my class project. I have a lead and a lead_comments table, lead has_many lead_comments and lead_comment belong_to lead, which I got those established.

In Model:

```
class Lead < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :lead_comments
end


class LeadComment < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :lead
end
```

In my lead's index view, I am trying to setup a date filter base on the Update_at in the lead_comments, which is the attribute from another table:

```
<div class="date-search">
  <%= form_tag leads_path, method: :get do %>
    <%= date_field_tag 'date_search[date_from]', @date_search.date_from %>
    <%= date_field_tag 'date_search[date_to]', @date_search.date_to %>
    <%= submit_tag 'Date Search' %>
  <% end %>
</div>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Phone Number</th>
      <th>Last Updated Date</th>
      <th colspan="3">Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @leads.each do |lead| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= lead.lead_firstname %></td>
        <td><%= lead.lead_lastname %></td>
        <td><%= lead.lead_phone %></td>
        <td><%= lead.lead_comments.maximum(:updated_at) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Detail', lead %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit/Update', edit_lead_path(lead) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Remove', lead, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

In my lead controller, I set up another controller for lead search purpose:

```
def index
    @date_search = LeadSearch.new(params[:date_search])
    @leads = @date_search.scope
end
```

In my lead search model, I believe where my problem is:

```
class LeadSearch
  attr_reader :date_from, :date_to

  def initialize(params)
    params ||= {}
    @date_from = parsed_date(params[:date_from], 30.days.ago.to_date.to_s)
    @date_to = parsed_date(params[:date_to], Date.today.to_s)
  end

  def scope
    Lead.lead_comments.maximum(:updated_at).where('updated_at BETWEEN ? AND ?', @date_from, @date_to)
  end

  private

  def parsed_date(date_string, default)
    Date.parse(date_string)
  rescue ArgumentError, TypeError
    default
  end
end
```

My lead_comment table only has one attributes, which is comment, along with the two automated date attributes created by Rails, created_at and updated_at.

Whenever I run the application I get an error that tells me undefined method "lead_comments".  I thought I have already established the has_many and belong_to relationship and this still not working.  Can someone please help me out and guide me to the right direction?  Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are doing Lead.lead_comments which is wrong. You are using the class name instead of the object. There should be a Lead model's object.

```
@lead.lead_comments
```

First, try your query in rails console. then use it in the controller for better perspective. try following,

```
Lead.lead_comments # will give error
```

instead use,

```
Lead.last.lead_comments # success
```

Answer (score 0):

Issues in your code:

1. `Lead.lead_comments`

Let's simplify this: think about `lead_comments` as a method that given a lead returns its comments. But we need a lead. That's why called on `Lead` does not work. That would work called on a `Lead` object.

2. `Lead.lead_comments.maximum(:updated_at)`

Here you're composing a SQL query though `ActiveRecord` but calling `maximum` stop this composition because that require a value so you're not able to call anything else after methods like `maximum`

Let's make your code work

```
def scope
  Lead.where('updated_at BETWEEN ? AND ?', @date_from, @date_to)
end
```

in your view

```
<td><%= lead.lead_comments.maximum(:updated_at) %></td>
```

Note here that this code has always been correct because you call `lead_comments` on a lead object.

I know, this performs one query for each `Lead` object but to make it works with just one query looks like another question